# Delete keys from redis server using redis-cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am trying to delete the KEYS using pattern from redis server but it is not getting deleted.

**Sample Keys**

```
1) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xa0\x01"
2) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\x98\x02"
3) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xb8\x02"
4) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x02\t!"
5) "flc_1310sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x02\t~"
6) "flc_1310sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xc0\x02"
7) "flc_-41sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xc5\x01"
8) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\x94\x03"
9) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xd3\x01"
10) "flc_77sandeep-pant-back.int.dev.mykronos.com_personality:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x0e\x03\x01SecondaryKe\xf9:\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03\t\xee\x02"
```

**Command**

```
redis-cli KEYS *sandeep-pant* | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

**Output**

```
xargs: WARNING: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
(integer) 0
```

Comment: `*` is a bash control character

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to write bash script use this one-liner

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "*sandeep-pant*" | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | xargs -i redis-cli del {}
```

Explanation:

1. Gets the matched keys line by line
2. sed adds quotes to the beginning and end of each key
3. xargs deletes the records one by one.

{} is the marker where the key should be placed in the script

Comment: Ah thanks, resolved my issue. This used to work fine without the sed bits but stopped working on some keys even though they don't appear to have any strange quotes/encoding.

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching around for a fix for my `xargs: unterminated quote` issue and this solved it.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `KEYS` as it is a blocking operation, use `SCAN` instead.
If you use glob pattern, surround it with quotes:

`redis-cli --scan --pattern '*sandeep-pant*' | xargs -L 100 redis-cli del`

You can use the `-L 100` to batch the `DEL` ops with 100 keys each time.

Comment: Yeah, this one much better then mine.

Answer (score 3):

Bash code:

```
for k in $(redis-cli -a password1 keys "*"); do
  echo "delete key '$k'";
  redis-cli -a password1 DEL $k;
done
```

Remove `-a password1` if not need a password

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to read the [documentation about `DEL`](https://redis.io/commands/del) - when you do, you'll notice that it does not accept key name patterns (i.e. wildcards), but requires the exact key names for deletion.

Comment: I tried deleting keys using pattern and it is working. [root@dmc31 ~]# redis-cli SET key1 "Hello"
OK
[root@dmc31 ~]# redis-cli SET key2 "World"
OK
[root@dmc31 ~]# redis-cli KEYS \*key\*
1) "key2"
2) "key1"
[root@dmc31 ~]# redis-cli KEYS \*key\* | xargs redis-cli DEL
(integer) 2

Answer (score 0):

If your redis key is inserted by spring boot redis application, and use JdkSerializationRedisSerializer, keys will start with like `\xac\xed\x00\x05w\x03`, xargs can not read that key normally, in this scenario, you can use lua script.

1. wirte lua script, saved as del.lua for example

   ```lua
   local key=KEYS[1]
   local list=redis.call("keys", key);
   for i,v in ipairs(list) do
       redis.call("del", v);
   end
   ```
2. use redis-cli call this script

   ```bash
   redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 --eval ./del.lua "*yourkeyspattern*"
   ```

If you have performace concerned, try replace redis KEYS with SCAN command in lua script.